# Objects to duplicate along a path and face the same direction

Tags: path

I have an object that duplicate along a curve but its orientation and shape change depending on its position on that path. I would need all the duplicates to remain intact and face the exact same direction. (facing camera)
Do you guys have an idea on how to achieve this? I've joined an image of the effect I'm heading for. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: what you can do is array a simple vertex along a curve (with Constant Offset), then parent your object to the vertex, keep the vertex selected and go in Object Data > Instancing and choose Verts

Comment: You're the man! It worked. Thx for the simple yet on point answer. :) cheers